# Не могу понять почему Maybe возвращает onSuccess

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Есть данные в базе

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM goodsentity")
Maybe<List<GoodsEntity>>  getAllGoodsEntity();
```

база пустая данные еще не инсертил .`Maybe` возвращает `onSucces` хотя по идеи если данных нет то должен вернуть `onComplete`

```
   getGoodsDao().getAllGoodsEntity()

                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        it->{
                            Log.e("Error","zero");
                        },
                        ex->{     Log.e("Error","ex");},
                        ()->{     Log.e("Error","emmpty");}
                );
```

возвращает zero а не empty ,почему и как сделать чтоб если данных нет возвращал `onSuccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому, что в `onSuccess` приходит пустой список. А `Maybe` вызовет `onComplete` только если `null` эмитит. Со списком в качестве возвращаемого значения работать `Maybe` не будет.

Если возвращаемым значением назначить не список, но просто `GoodsEntity` - получите [ожидаемое поведение](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/533-urok-9-room-rxjava.html).

Судя по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47769274/3212712) вам может помочь фильтрация пустого списка для получения ожидаемого поведения:

```
maybeWhichEmitsList
    .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
```

Comment: привет!)мой сенсей)))ты когда в мск будешь хотел бы тебя отблагодарить)

Comment: @elik, привет) Я помню) Коли буду в МСК - дам знать)